# How to display an alert immediately when a condition is met?

Tags: javascript, html, liquid

I'm trying to make an alert for when a total price in a cart is over $100.

I used a simple if statement, and when the condition is met, show alert. Below is my code inside the HTML  (I'm modifying Shopify's theme).

```
<script>
  function showAlert() { alert('You triggered an alert!'); }
</script>
{% if cart.total_price > 100 %}
  <script>showAlert();</script>
{% endif%}
```

This is close, but not quite what I want. It only shows the alert after I refresh the page. I want the alert to show right when the cart hits $100. So, when I add a product and it totals to over $100, I want the alert to show right away. How do I do this?

Comment: How are items added to your cart? Based on your question, it sounds like items are added without the entire page being refreshed; if that's the case, you need to add some AJAX calls to update your total as each item is added, and then call your check after each addition. If you could post a bit more of your code that illustrates how items are added, it would help us give you a more robust answer. Good luck!

Comment: Please take the [tour] (you get a badge!), have a look around, and read through the [help], in particular [*How do I ask a good question?*](/help/how-to-ask) I also recommend Jon Skeet's [Writing the Perfect Question](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/). You'll need to modify (or add) the JavaScript on the page. We can't help you do that without the relevant code (and the question is too broad for SO's format anyway).

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13840429/what-is-the-difference-between-client-side-and-server-side-programming

Answer (score -1):

there was a method previously supported in browser now deprecated  Object.watch which can be use to implement your requirement but you can you use the following poly fill for that.

```js
  if (!Object.prototype.watch) {
        Object.defineProperty(Object.prototype, "watch", {
          enumerable: false
          , configurable: true
          , writable: false
          , value: function (prop, handler) {
            var
              oldval = this[prop]
              , newval = oldval
              , getter = function () {
                return newval;
              }
              , setter = function (val) {
                oldval = newval;
                return newval = handler.call(this, prop, oldval, val);
              }
            ;

            if (delete this[prop]) { // can't watch constants
              Object.defineProperty(this, prop, {
                get: getter
                , set: setter
                , enumerable: true
                , configurable: true
              });
            }
          }
        });
      }

    var cart = {price: 40}
    cart.watch('price', (name, prev, current) => {
 if(current > 100) {
  alert(`your price is ${current} dollars which is greater than 100`);
 }
    })
    cart.price = 140
```